# browser.wait in non-angular site for protractor

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I have to test a proyect with AngularJS and with no AngularJS pages. My problem is how to wait load all the elements of the non Angular page before starting the methods element, expect...

```
  browser.executeScript('return jQuery.active;').then(function (text) {
        console.log(text);
    });
```

This works and returned 0 (the site is loaded), so this way I know all is loaded. My doubt is how to use

```
      browser.executeScript('return jQuery.active;')
```

with ***browser.wait*** function.

Answer (score 0):

`browser.wait()` keeps on waiting until `true` is returned until a certain timeout value.  Following should do the trick for you.

```
browser.wait(function(){
  return browser.executeScript('return jQuery.active;').then(function (text) {
    return text == 0;
  });          
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I test it and tell you!